# Magento Adminhtml Controller looking for the wrong URL

Tags: adminhtml, admin-controller

So I'm trying to make an Admin menu for a module I'm developing. The menu itself displays fine but when I click on it I get a 404 page.

This is my code:

Jiri/Servicepunten/etc/config.xml

```
<modules>
    <Jiri_Servicepunten>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Jiri_Servicepunten>
</modules>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Jiri_Servicepunten after="Mage_Adminhtml">Jiri_Servicepunten
                    </Jiri_Servicepunten>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Jiri/Servicepunten/etc/adminhtml.xml

```
 <config>
<menu>
    <service translate="title" module="jiri_servicepunten">
        <title>Service</title>
        <sort_order>50</sort_order>
        <children>
            <servicepunten>
                <title>Servicepunten</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/Servicepunten</action>
            </servicepunten>
        </children>
    </service>
</menu>
```

Jiri/Servicepunten/controllers/ServicepuntenController.php

```
 class Jiri_Servicepunten_ServicepuntenController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{
public function indexAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

}

When I try to debug the controller filename in core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php it looks in the following place:

```
 app/code//Jiri/Servicepunten/////////////////////////controllers/ServicepuntenController.php"
```

I'm not sure where all the slashes are coming from. Its in the local pool btw. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out my code was okay. Except for where it says

```
 <Jiri_Servicepunten after="Mage_Adminhtml">Jiri_Servicepunten
 </Jiri_Servicepunten>
```

All that whitespace between the tags apparently got registered as extra slashes. If I put the closing tag immediatly after the string it works as intended.